# How to connect Android phone with microchip controller device?

Tags: android

I want to make an application through which i can send messages  via the USB in order to control port pins on an 8 bit controller - a Microchip  USB enabled device.
Can u give any link through there is sample example  is given to connect Android phone to microchip

PLz help...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the Android Accessories Development Kit. The original kit was based on the Arduino (an ATMega MCU), but Microchip have their own version based on their PIC 24F:
http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en553673